# kernel name in grub menu vs kernel.conf

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, alma-linux

I'm trying to know the difference between changing something in the name of the kernel in the grub menu vs changing the content of the name of the kernel in the .conf file in the /boot/loader/entries.

If I change something in the grub, it does not affect the content of the .conf file and i do not know why.

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GRUB is almost completely read-only: the only thing it can write is environment variables into a pre-allocated file, `/boot/grub/grubenv` - and that only when you explicitly use the `save_env` command.

When you change something in the GRUB menu or GRUB shell, the change will be **non-persistent**: it will affect the on-going boot attempt only, and the next time the system is booted, the configuration will be unchanged.

To make persistent changes, you must boot an operating system that includes full-featured, write-capable drivers for the appropriate

- disk controller
- partitioning/LVM/RAID scheme
- filesystem type

and then you'll be able to change the appropriate files the usual way.

(Or if you need to use an OS that cannot support the filesystem type, you technically could use a disk editor to poke at the file contents and filesystem metadata directly at a very low level, but that usually qualifies as pretty high-grade wizardry these days...)

Comment: Thank you very much!